# The package react@15.2.1 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

When trying to `npm install` I get these errors.
Can't get why it's not running if I'm using the latest version of React.

`npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react@15.2.1 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-addons-css-transition-group@15.2.1 wants react@^15.2.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-animate-on-change@0.2.0 wants react@^0.14.5
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-dom@15.2.1 wants react@^15.2.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-dropdown@1.0.4 wants react@^0.14.7 || ^15.0.0-0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-masonry-component@4.2.0 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-modal@1.4.0 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-native@0.29.0 wants react@~15.2.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-redux@4.4.5 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-router@2.5.2 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-toastr@2.7.0 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer redux-devtools@3.3.1 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-rc.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because other packages in your project wants lower version of React, like 15.0, but not 15.2. You can read more about peerDependencies here https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/#the-solution-peer-dependencies and here https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#peerdependencies

Solution for your problem, do not upgrade your React version till you update other libraries.

Answer (score 7):

You could also update npm to version 3. The new version will ensure you don't have this issue.